# Is it possible to print out strings in a waveform with vhdl

Tags: vhdl, quartus

Say it was for a FSM and I wanted to print out the current state every clock cycle.  How would I go about doing so? What datatype would I need?

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @Qiu Using Quartus

Comment: If your states are values of an enumerated type you should be able to display them symbolically.  (What does your state type declaration look like?)

Comment: What do you mean "print out" : in simulation, Morten shows you how to use the Wave window; I generally use the console, with "Assert" or "Report".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, waveforms in e.g. ModelSim can show `string`, and that can be very handy.  A quick example below:

```
architecture sim of tb is

  signal info : string(1 to 20);

  function string_fill(msg : string; len : natural) return string is
    variable res_v : string(1 to len);
  begin
    res_v := (others => ' ');  -- Fill with spaces to blank all for a start
    res_v(1 to msg'length) := msg;
    return res_v;
  end function;

begin

  process is
  begin
    info <= string_fill("Hello VHDL", info'length);
    wait for 100 ns;
    info <= string_fill("Hi Bren", info'length);
    wait for 100 ns;
    info <= string_fill("end of sim", info'length);
    wait for 100 ns;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Which shows:

[image]

Note that string manipulation can be a little tricky in VHDL, but if you just need some for simple debug output, then the above may do it.